# Question about Einstein notation

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

If for a second rank tensor $T_{\mu\nu}$, the following equation holds
$$\partial^\mu T_{\mu\nu}=0$$,can we have
$$\eta^{\mu\nu} \eta_{\mu\nu}\partial^\mu T_{\mu\nu}=0=\partial^\mu \eta^{\mu\nu} \eta_{\mu\nu} T_{\mu\nu}=\partial^\mu \eta_{\mu\nu}T=0$$
(where $\eta^{\mu\nu}$
,$\eta_{\mu\nu}$ are  Minkowski metric tensors), and hence $\partial^\mu(T_{\mu\nu}-\eta_{\mu\nu}T)=0$,
Is this correct?

Comment: Hi YuJuchong123. Please don't change the question after it has been answered.

Answer (score 4):

No, you've used the indices too many times.  In Einstein notation, indices may appear at *most* twice, once upstairs and once downstairs.